# mutipass:launch failed: Failed to resize instance image - error executing powershell command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multipass

I always have the following error when I install a virtual machine

launch failed: Failed to resize instance image - error executing powershell command. Detail: Resize-VHD : �޷������������̵Ĵ�С��
ϵͳ�޷�������C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\multipassd\vault\instances\krun\ubuntu-20.04-serv
er-cloudimg-amd64.vhdx���Ĵ�С��
�޷������������̵Ĵ�С��
ϵͳ�޷�������C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\multipassd\vault\instances\krun\ubuntu-20.04-serv
er-cloudimg-amd64.vhdx���Ĵ�С: ��һ����������ʹ�ô��ļ��������޷����ʡ� (0x80070020)��
����λ�� ��:1 �ַ�: 1

- Resize-VHD -Path C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Roa ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceBusy: (:) [Resize-VHD], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ObjectInUse,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResizeVhd
  ```

Comment: Command-line code:multipass launch -n krun -c 8 -m 8G -d  32G

Answer (score 0):

## Background

In my case, I changed the location of my multipass instance locations by following this post [here.](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/pull/1789) I then created a folder on my drive where I wanted the instances to be stored.

After doing so, `multipass launch` failed with your exact same error. After trying reboots, uninstall/reinstall multipass, etc. - I finally tried renaming the folder where I wanted to store my multipass instances, and this worked.

Apparently, if your destination multipass folder includes a space, some part of the script fails.

## Workaround / Fix

When specifying a multipass instance destination:
`MULTIPASS_STORAGE -Value "<path>"`

Make sure there are **NO SPACES** in the `"<path>"` you have provided.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the HyperV module to powershell in "Turn Windows features on or off", if you don't check this the checkbox, "Resize-VHD" won't work and will fail the multipass launch.

The direct command is:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName  Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell`